# Failed to switch between android apps during appium automation

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have the below code.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities =DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","hammerhead");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.calculator2");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/digit_7']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/op_add']")).click();
driver.startActivity("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
```

"java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" error is thrown on executing driver.startActivity line. What mistake I'm making here?

Answer (score 0):

> **Invocation Target Exception:-** This exception occurs when an underlying method throws an exception. So if there is any method that is invoked using `Reflection API` throws any runtime exception, the Reflection API will wrap that exception in `InvocationTargetException`

You can figure out the original/actual `exception` by using `getCause()` method on the `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: cause: null
target: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

Comment: so now you got the error, you can proceed ahead with the solution. JVM isn't able to find your class definition.

Comment: I kept commons-lang-2.6 in build path. Still the error exists. But how come this exception is thrown from driver.startActivity()?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too.  This is due to the problem of StringUtils.  I downloaded Apache Commons Lang plugin and problem was solved.

The download can be found here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

After downloading, add commons-lang3-3.4.jar to your external libraries in your IDE.